# Training accuracy increase abruptly at first epoch to 99%. is it normal?

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow, adam

I expected my training process is like this:

[image]

But my training accuracy increased to 99% at only 1 epoch, not steadily increase.

I was suspicious about high learning rate, so i used various learning rate(0.001~0.00001). But the training accuracy increased to ~99% at only one epoch and kept 99% ~ 100%.

Otherwise, validation accuracy increased to ~70% at one epoch and increased up to 80% during 2~3 epoch, and then oscillated during training.

Another problem is that, training loss is almost 0, thereby only weight decay term remain in loss function. it caused weights to become all 0.

I don't know what is problem. Is input image size too small?

---

below is my detail setting:

---

I'm using convolutional 1~5th layer weights from *Alexnet*, for fine-tune my CNN network.

Difference between *Alexnet* is that, my input image size is 87x33 unlike 224x224 in *Alexnet*.

(Accordingly, my last(5) conv feature shape is 4x2x256, fully connected layer is same as *Alexnet*).

Number of classes are two(positive, negative) in my network.

Number of training image data for positive is ~40k, for negative is ~40k.

(apply random crop,warping,flipping for each sampling)

I used *Adam-optimizer* in tensorflow.

---

EDIT:

I checked training samples are different per feeding,
and i'm pretty sure that it's not a problem.

By the way, i realized that i use subset of *ImageNet* data for fine-tuning(as i know, *AlexNet* is trained by *ImageNet*, as well).

Although, i only used pre-trained weights for conv-layer(1~5) 
and i only used *ImageNet* data for negative training image, not for positives,
i think it's the cause for my problem.

is it make sense?

Comment: Unless your data is trivial to classify, no it's not normal, certainly not for large conv network.

Comment: Can you draw a graph for you network like your question?

Comment: What are you training your data on? For instance, if you train your data to predict a binary classification i.e.(1/0) and the average of 1's = 60% the model will first use this 60% as baseline, since it is simply able to predict with a 60% accuracy by saying everything should become a 1.

Answer (score 2):

Check than the batch is giving different samples, looks like you are feeding always the same samples to the network...
Another thing you have to understand, is that you are using a pretrained model, which means that lots of patterns are already learnt, if your data fit in those patterns, is it possible than your problem was already solved in the model.

Comment: I missed the part OP mentioned about the pre-trained weights when I was reading the question. Thanks for pointing out.